# how to load brands on ecommerce product load for Infinite Scroll

Tags: reactjs, web, e-commerce, infinite-scroll, software-design

On my eCommerce site, I'm loading all the products from **"food-and-grocery"** using **[react-infinite-scroller](https://github.com/danbovey/react-infinite-scroller)**. That is working fine.

How should I load related product's brands, sections, ratings data (which users check/select to filter products) ?
I don't want to load all the brands from my database, instead, I want to load only those brands, sections those who are relevant to loaded products. What would be a good approach to do that?

Referencing below image, the blue section is for products which is loading using infinite scroll. I want to load data for the right side's **red** section. And want expert suggestion, how to do that in right way?

[image]